# Why is the '3D Objects' folder not in the Blender file browser quick access menu panel?

Tags: file-browser

Is there a particular reason why the "3D Objects" folder (part of user files & folders) is missing in the Blender 'File > Open...' file quick access menu list (which contains "Home", "Desktop", "Documents", "Downloads", "Music", "Pictures", "Videos", "Fonts" - BUT NOT "3D Objects" - which is weird because Blender is all about 3D Objects..)?

[image: Image of the menu]

Comment: Likely because older versions of windows don't have that folder.

Answer (score 1):

My personal work around was to add it to my Favorites section by going to

`C:\Users\[username]\3D Objects`

Then entering the folder, and then in the Favorites section, either clicking on the + button, or right clicking in the *Favorites* window and choosing *Add Bookmark* from the menu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.